# Delete-file option before opening a file using QFile::Append

Tags: c++, qt

Most of the time I want to iteratively add a line to a file, but before I open the file to append to, I'd want to be sure it is an empty file to start with (delete if exists).

It occurs so often that I am guessing there might be something I overlook.

So, what is the most convenient way to remove a file first before appending?

```
QFile outfile(filename);
if (outfile.open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text))  
// An option like `QFile::DELETE_FIRST` or something would be great.
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `QFile::Append` - it will open file in append mode, so that all dta is written to the end of the file. You can see all `OpenModeFlag`'s [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum). Use `QIODevice::Truncate` instead.

> QIODevice::Truncate   If possible, the device is truncated before it is opened. All earlier contents of the device are lost.

Comment: I do want to append though, line by line. Is it possible to just add this to the file opening options?

Comment: You still want to Truncate. This will not prevent you from appending line by line to the end of the open file.

Comment: Does this mean that I could just call `outfile.Truncate` before appending?

Comment: I am still not sure how to apply this.